# How to get 2 least significant byte from a integer in c?

Tags: c

```
unsigned char x=0;
//int num is some random integer
x=num;
```

How to get 2 least significant bytes?

Comment: [bit-twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)

Comment: Please ask a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), if you have one. Do not change this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to get 2 least significant bytes?

```
int least = (signed)((unsigned)num & ~((~0U)<<(2*CHAR_BIT)));
```

`CHAR_BIT` is a preprocessor-constant equal to the number of bits in a byte, which is a minimum of 8.
I use `unsigned` integral types, because bit-twiddling `signed` types is fraught with peril.
`-1U` is all-bits-1, due to modulo arithmetic on unsigned types, same as `~0U`.

Answer (score 7):

Since you want the two least significant bytes, you will need two unsigned chars to hold the two bytes since unsigned char is just a byte in length.

```
unsigned char x, y;
x = 0x00FF & num; // Get the first least significant byte.
y = (0xFF00 & num) >> 8; // Gets the second least significant byte and store it in the char.
```

Comment: `0x00FF` etc, surely.

Comment: Ah yeah, lol, brain fart, edited to fix that. Thanks, you two!

Comment: Get the second least significant byte with masking, and discarding all non-zero bits by assigning to `char`?

Comment: The question wasn't exactly clear on how exactly he wants the bytes (in one variable, two separate variables, etc.). So I just decided to put them all in separate variables for clarity. I just realized, y is actually invalid since unsigned char cannot hold anything more than a byte, so I'm taking that out.

Comment: How to get bytes for char/cstring like t or \0?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but a byte IS an unsigned char, so there is really no need to "convert". In fact, I believe a `byte` is just a `typedef` of an `unsigned char`

Comment: @EdwardL.: A byte and a char are equivalent in C (and thus C++), being the smallest addressable unit of memory, and a minimum of 8 bit big (Look at `CHAR_BIT` for the exact number). If you speak of the windows `BYTE`, that's an `unsigned char`, yes.